# How many options there are for $n$ people to shake hands exactly $r$ times?

Tags: combinatorics

> Find how many options there are for $n$ people to shake hands exactly $r$ times while:
>
> - The same pair of people can't shake hands more than once
> - Order of hand shakes does not matter

So the solution I thought about is ordering all people, then first deciding who the first person shakes hand with which is $2^{n-1}$ options, then who the second person shakes hands with (all options except the first person who we already counted) and so on, so in total we get $2^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(n-i)}$ options, so the solution is $\binom{2^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(n-i)}}{r}$.

I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution without summation. Also would be nice to confirm my solution is not wrong in some way.

Comment: Shaking hands is not recommended due to the Corona Virus pandemy :)

Comment: @JeanMarie I agree, my professor gives very inappropriate homework

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you're counting the number of labeled $r$-regular graphs, which is an unsolved problem

Comment: The formulation of the problem is ambiguous. In my answer, I interpreted it to mean that all $n$ people in total do $r$ handshakes, but @stochastic apparently interpreted it to mean that each person does $r$ handshakes. Which do you mean?

Comment: @joriki your interpretation is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be counting subsets and then choosing $r$ of the subsets. But the task is not to choose $r$ subsets but to choose $r$ pairs.

The solution is actually quite straightforward. There are $\binom n2$ unordered pairs of people, and the $r$ of these pairs who shake hands can be chosen in $\binom{\binom n2}r$ ways.

Comment: thanks, I see why my solution is wrong

Comment: There is a restriction : the number is $0$ is $n$ and $r$ are both odd ; see (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2113127).

Comment: @JeanMarie: It seems you're operating under a different interpretation of the question than was intended; see the comments under the question.

Comment: @joriki I see. I should have paid more attention !

Comment: A little follow up (might open as a new question later, idk):

How many options are there if we know each person participates at least once?

I solved it with Inclusion-Exclusion but I wonder if there's a simpler solution

Comment: @paxtibimarce: I would have done it with inclusion–exclusion, too; I don't immediately see a simpler solution. Let me know if you post a question about this.